# Returning a value even if no result

Tags: mysql

I have this kind of simple query that returns a not null integer field for a given id:

```
SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE id = 123 LIMIT 1;
```

The thing is if the id is not found, the resultset is empty. I need the query to always return a value, even if there is no result.

I have this thing working but I don't like it because it runs 2 times the same subquery:

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id = 123) = 1, (SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE id = 123 LIMIT 1), 0);
```

It returns either field1 if the row exists, otherwise 0. Any way to improve that?

Thanks!

**Edit following some comments and answers**: yes it has to be in a **single query statement** and I can not use the count trick because **I need to return only 1 value** (FYI I run the query with the Java/Spring method SimpleJdbcTemplate.queryForLong()).

Comment: Does this need to be done in a single query statement? Otherwise you could declare a variable with a default, select into it, then select the variable.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

MySQL has a function to return a value if the result is null. You can use it on a whole query:

```
SELECT IFNULL( (SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE id = 123 LIMIT 1) ,'not found');
```

Comment: Good catch to put the whole query in the IFNULL! Actually I tried something similar: SELECT IFNULL(field1, 0) FROM table WHERE id = 123 LIMIT 1; but it was not working (no result), I didn't think of putting the whole query in IFNULL...

Comment: This is the best answer on SO to this often asked question. Side note, `COALESCE()` also works in place of `IFNULL()`.  Not sure if there's a performance difference but I'm used to `COALESCE()` so it's easier to remember.

Comment: `COALESCE()` will continue to find no null value. then has over than one parameter. http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/coalesce.php

Comment: This requires running the SELECT statement twice.  Once to check if it can be found, and another to actually find it.  That's double the load on the MySQL server for the exact same results.  See solution below by MarkNHopGood .

Comment: Upvote! Never thought about using the `IFNULL` on the whole query!

Answer (score 42):

As you are looking for 1 record, (LIMIT 1) then this will work.

```
(SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE id = 123) 
UNION 
(SELECT 'default_value_if_no_record')
LIMIT 1;
```

Can be a handy way to display default values, or indicate no results found. I use it for reports.

See also http://blogs.uoregon.edu/developments/2011/03/31/add-a-header-row-to-mysql-query-results/ for a way to use this to create headers in reports.

Comment: Extremely useful!!  I swapped 'default_value_if_no_record' with "null" (no quotes) and it produced the desired output.  Perfect, thanks!

Comment: ingenious my friend!

Comment: Yes, this is a pretty old post, but wanted to mention that `union` does not guarantee any order, so it's entirely possible that the 1 entry which gets returned would be the default row and not the result.  I'm not aware of any implementation that would actually shuffle this simple result set, but it's really not safe to depend on that behavior.  The [doc page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) mentions this and gives a solution involving dummy sorting column if you REALLY wanna use this approach, but it starts getting a little messy.

Comment: Sometimes mysql can return empty string, and UNION will not catch.

Solution:

`(SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE id = 123 AND field1 <> '') 
UNION 
(SELECT 'default_value_if_no_record')
LIMIT 1;`

Comment: AS @AC mentions, UNION does not guarantee order, but if you are trying to return a simple Y or N flag, you can alias the field and use ORDER BY to ensure you get the correct order: `(SELECT IF(field IS NULL, 'N', 'Y') AS flag FROM table WHERE id = 123)  UNION  (SELECT 'N' AS flag) ORDER BY flag DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: the clever one!

Answer (score 21):

You could include count(id). That will always return.

```
select count(field1), field1 from table where id = 123 limit 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64c76/4

Comment: Or even: `SELECT 1, field FROM table WHERE ...`

Comment: No. That won't work. Neither will min, max, sum or most of the other functions. Basically I always stick to count as I know that works.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I was under the impression it worked but in effect I just tried and it does not

Comment: Cant use GROUP by with this one.

Comment: @Andreas Wederbrand actually sum() can work when used correctly...e.g 
select ifnull(sum(record_number), 13)
from bch_trans_file where 7=9;

Comment: @Uncle Iroh When using group by it won't work. I tried select ifnull(sum(1), 0) from part where 1 = 2 group by part_code; in my database but it returns no row.

Comment: @PLAYMAKER - Yeah see Hariboo's comment as well.  Group by ruins it.  It's fragile to begin with.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(column),0)
FROM   table
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone is looking to use this to insert the result INTO a variable and then using it in a Stored Procedure; you can do it like this:

```sql
DECLARE date_created INT DEFAULT 1;
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT date FROM monthly_comission WHERE date = date_new_month LIMIT 1), 0) 
INTO date_created 
WHERE IFNULL((SELECT date FROM monthly_comission WHERE date = date_new_month LIMIT 1), 0) = 0;
```

With this you're storing in the variable 'date_created' 1 or 0 (if returned nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Do search with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. I don't know if MySQL allows inline `VALUES` in join clauses but you can have predefined table for this purposes.

Answer (score 0):

k-a-f's answer works for selecting one column, if selecting multiple column, we can.

```
DECLARE a BIGINT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE b BIGINT DEFAULT "name";

SELECT id, name from table into a,b;
```

Then we just need to check a,b for values.

Answer (score 0):

if you want both always a return value but never a null value you can combine count with coalesce :

```
select count(field1), coalesce(field1,'any_other_default_value') from table;
```

that because count, will force mysql to always return a value (0 if there is no values to count) and coalesce will force mysql to always put a value that is not null

Answer (score 0):

if you want only one result then you can use aggerate functions. Cause aggerate function print null if there is no value found.
I can give you 2 solutions.

solution1,

```
SELECT
      max(field1)
FROM 
(SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE id = 123);
```

Solution2,

```
(SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE id = 123 LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT NULL)
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into almost this same situation except the query in question sometimes returned 0 rows, or sometimes it could be multiple rows.  With multiple rows, you can't use IFNULL as described by K.A.F.  In that case, you can use a LEFT JOIN on a dummy field to force MySQL to return a NULL record instead of returning no rows.  You can then use a CASE statement to convert that null into something more descriptive.

For instance:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN b.field1 is NULL then "No Records" else b.field1 end as "field1" from
(SELECT '1' as dummy from table limit 1) a
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT field1, '1' as dummy FROM table WHERE id = 123) b
ON a.dummy = b.dummy;
```

If "field1" comes back with no records, the LEFT JOIN will force it to come back with a "NULL" instead, then the SELECT CASE translates that into "No Records".  If "field1" has records, you'll get those records instead.

For the record, my situation was related to variable in a Grafana dashboard.  The variable would sometimes come back with 0 records and, since that variable was being used in an "IN" list in the WHERE clause of the query for one of the panels, the empty list from the variable would cause the query to error out.  Using the approach above allowed me to return a descriptive "NULL" value for the variable informing the user appropriately, and also causing the panel query to behave appropriately.