# mysql - select value if no result

Tags: mysql

ok, my question today is that:
i want to get data from table according to criteria.
if no result i want it to use a given value.
my query looks like that :

```
select  distinct COALESCE(table.Name,'a') as name, 
'b' as val1, 
'c' as val2,  
'd' as val3 
from  table 
where table.Id='255';
```

If there is Id 255 I want the query to return the name with that id.
otherwise, I want it to return the value 'a'.
other fields should return their values anyway.
when I use the above query I get an empty result set because there is no Id = '255' in table.

anyone?
thanks a lot

Comment: Has been asked and answered before. Unfortunately I dont know how to mark this post as a duplicate... So I'm just gonna give you the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449899/returning-a-value-even-if-no-result EDIT: Found out and flagged it... should be fixed soon.

Comment: You want to return 'a' if the result set is empty (no row with that id) and the value of 'name' if there is a result, right? Youre not looking for IFNULL I guess

Comment: yep, you right. ifnull was my first guess. i used the COALESCE function because someone said its better then ifnull function. anyway it does the same job, but not the job i want..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning a value even if no result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449899/returning-a-value-even-if-no-result)