# Set default value if no result found

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query

```
SELECT count(*) as count, Month(created_at) as month 
FROM products 
WHERE marketplace_id=21
      and status='counterfeit' 
      and created_at < Now() 
      and created_at > DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL - 5 MONTH)
group by month(created_at)
```

it return result as

```
+-------+-------+
| count | month |
+-------+-------+
|   410 |     1 |
|   174 |     2 |
|   301 |     3 |
|   329 |     4 |
|   141 |    12 |
+-------+-------+
```

in case a month does not have values it doesn't returns it at all, but I want the default value 0 to be set for that month.

I have tried [this link Return a default value if no rows found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319264/return-a-default-value-if-no-rows-found)
and

[Returning a value if no result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449899/returning-a-value-even-if-no-result)

I am not sure whether I am not able to implement it correctly or this is not what I want

Comment: May be create a calendar table and store only the months (12 rows) and do a left join to that table.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, seems to be a little stupid, but may help for you;)

```
SELECT SUM(count) AS count, month
FROM (
    SELECT count(*) as count, Month(created_at) as month FROM products WHERE marketplace_id=21
            and status='counterfeit' and created_at < Now() and created_at > DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL - 5 MONTH)
            group by month(created_at)
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 0 AS count, 1 AS month
        UNION SELECT 0 AS count, 2 AS month
        UNION SELECT 0 AS count, 3 AS month
        UNION SELECT 0 AS count, 4 AS month
        UNION SELECT 0 AS count, 5 AS month
        UNION SELECT 0 AS count, 6 AS month
        UNION SELECT 0 AS count, 7 AS month
        UNION SELECT 0 AS count, 8 AS month
        UNION SELECT 0 AS count, 9 AS month
        UNION SELECT 0 AS count, 10 AS month
        UNION SELECT 0 AS count, 11 AS month
        UNION SELECT 0 AS count, 12 AS month) M
    WHERE M.month < Month(Now()) AND M.month > Month(DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL - 5 MONTH)))
) tmp
GROUP BY mouth
ORDER BY month
```

Comment: ok this works, but the problem here is it is giving value for whole year, what if I am starting from august and want data of past six months Aug, Jul, Jun,May,Apr and Mar

Comment: Something like `where month >= Month(created_at)`

Comment: Hmm, what you guys said is definitely right, I've updated my post, check it again pls.

Answer (score 1):

You could create another table with default values

```
  test_defaults
-----------------
| month | count |
```

and than just `left join` it with your table of values so if the value is found within the main table, it will be used, if not value from test_defaults would be used (we will use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function which returns first non null value):

```
SELECT t1.month, COALESCE(t2.count, t1.count)
FROM test_defaults t1
LEFT JOIN test_data t2 ON t1.month = t2.month
ORDER BY t1.month;
```

[Here's a working SqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d022b/1)