# MySQL: Returning Multiple values even if no results

Tags: mysql, sql

[Previous Solution for one Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449899/returning-a-value-even-if-no-result)

Is there a way to return multiple NULL or 'nan' values if we have a query with multiple ID values? In other words, if a table has a datetime "ID" which is a primary key. It is incrementing in ticks of one second. Some of those seconds (entries) are missing and you would want to return 'nan' or 'empty' once you query a large range of IDs.

Working Code for one value:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID in ('2017-06-29 23:10:00') UNION ALL (SELECT 'nan') LIMIT 1
```

Trying to achieve dynamic query for multiple values. In this example, I query 3 IDs, but the list can grow to thousands - non-working Example:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID in ('2017-06-29 23:10:00', '2017-06-29 23:10:01','2017-06-30 00:11:03') UNION ALL (SELECT 'nan') LIMIT 1
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a [SQL "gaps-and-islands"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands+sql) problem.  Many questions here deal with "missing days" in data series.  Your problem is essentially the same, except that you have missing seconds.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Can you show the table contents and the desired results?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `UNION` to synthesize a table with all the IDs you want to match, then left join this with the real table. When there's no match in the table, `LEFT JOIN` results in `NULL` for its columns, and you can test for this and show the default value.

```
SELECT IFNULL(t2.id, 'nan') AS id
FROM (SELECT '2017-06-29 23:10:00' as id
      UNION ALL
      SELECT '2017-06-29 23:10:01'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT '2017-06-29 23:10:02') AS t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

See [What is the most straightforward way to pad empty dates in sql results (on either mysql or perl end)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752/) for how you can automate the process of creating the table with all the timestamps.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure this will do the trick. I will update the question with more clarification.

Comment: So you're looking for multiple rows, not multiple columns?