# Arrange and array in a order in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a table where multiple images are uploaded .. the fields in the table are

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
id,user_id,photo,position
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

There can be **maximum 8 images** against a user id.

Now if an user upload image in suppose 1 , 3 , 5 position

And when i have to return the array after fetching from the database

i will get the value for the 1 , 3 , 5 position but i have to return the array with all the position that is from 1 to 8

So as per the requiremnet position 1 will have the value of 1 from the database as there is value in the database but there is no value against position 2 so in the array the position 2 will be blank...

Basically the position that have value in database will hold the value from the database and those position that doesn't have values in database will be blank

> positions are 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

How to do it in php?

Comment: see here for numeric index arrays example with gaps in indexes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-60

Comment: Select them in order?

Comment: then what happens to `user_2`? should the ids be 9->16?

Comment: @Scuzzy Select them in order means  ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12450344/4248328  (you can do it at sql end using `IFNULL`)

Comment: @AlexTartan user_2 will also have position 1 to 8

Comment: @AlexTartan postion are from the front end where the image will be displayed.... if the user upload an image in postion 1 then it will save in the database as postion 1

Comment: @Samim, hi perhaps it's easier for others to understand your question if you give examples of input and desired output arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select an array with position as keys of array
for example..

```
$image[position] = image_name;
```

Code

```
$image[1] = image1;
$image[3] = $image3;
$image[5] = $image5;
```

Now run a for loop  as follows

```
for($i=0;$i<8;$i++){
    if(!isset($image[$i])) $image[$i] = '';
}
```

You got the result what you want as $image array;

Answer (score 0):

You can't get from table value that does not exists there. So write code like this

```
$Something = 'test';
$aFromTable = array (1=>$Something,3=>$Something,5=>$Something);

for ($i=1;$i<9;$i++)
{
    if (!isset($aFromTable[$i]))
        $aFromTable[$i] = $Something;
}

var_dump($aFromTable);
```

or  like this

```
$Something = 'test';
$aStandard[1] =  null;
$aStandard[2] =  null;
$aStandard[3] =  null;
$aStandard[4] =  null;
$aStandard[5] =  null;
$aStandard[6] =  null;
$aStandard[7] =  null;
$aStandard[8] =  null;
$aFromTable = array (1=>$Something,3=>$Something,5=>$Something);


$aFromTable = $aFromTable + $aStandard;
var_dump($aFromTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$rows = [
    ['foo.jpg', 8],
    ['bar.jpg', 4],
    ['baz.jpg', 1]
];

$positions = array_fill(1, 8, null);

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $positions[$row[1]] = $row[0];
}

var_export($positions);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 'baz.jpg',
  2 => NULL,
  3 => NULL,
  4 => 'bar.jpg',
  5 => NULL,
  6 => NULL,
  7 => NULL,
  8 => 'foo.jpg',
)
```

Example SQL used to produce a rows array:

```
SELECT photo, position FROM photo_table WHERE user_id = 3
```